# Accessing data from array in rendered list in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I am trying to use a property from a rendered list which may change depending on if a checkbox is filled or not. However, mathSkill and scienceSkill always show 0. I feel like I'm doing something very wrong in trying to access booleanValue but I am not sure what else I could put in the if statement to allow it to update the values. Thank you in advance if you have any insight!

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    abilities: [
      { value: 'math', id: 'math', booleanValue:'no' },
      { value: 'science', id: 'science', booleanValue:'no'},
      { value: 'english', id: 'english', booleanValue:'no'},
     ],
    // VARIABLES
    mathSkill: 0,
    scienceSkill: 0,
  },
  computed: {
    addToMath: function() {
      if (this.abilities[0] === 'yes' )
        mathSkill = mathSkill +1,
        scienceSkill = scienceSkill + 1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.abilities[0]` gives you an object. you need to continue to chain the accessor method off of the `[0]` to target the property

Comment: I tried this.abilties[0].booleanValue and still no luck! Or am I completely off ? Thank you

Comment: thank you this has worked. I forgot to use this inside the computed if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Don't define the variables, if you are going to calculate them.

Use `.filter` to make a new array based on some condition, and use `.length` to get how many objects in that array

```js
computed: {
    matchSkill() { return this.abilities.filter(ability => ability.booleanValue === "yes").length},
}
```

[Example code](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Well I'd like to do some calculations based on if a checkbox is selected, changing the boolean value. So only filter yes combined with 'math' for example to modify the mathSkil value. Thank you ! I will try this.